# Simple way to assign javascript variable to php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

Any help will be appreciated. I just want to assign javascript variables inside php code.can you guys sort it.

From the above code.. Need to assign var gtitle into `do_shortcode()`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">  
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on('click', '.map' , function(){
            var gtitle = $(this).data("fpid");
            <?php $data = do_shortcode('+gtitle+'); ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your php code only runs when the page is first loaded therefore the click event is ignored. If you view source of your page you might see some rubbish info there. You might also see that the page has produced a JavaScript error.

Comment: yes @jeff its showing error now..but what I am trying is  <?php $data = do_shortcode(); ?> $data will be blank onpage load. After onclick event it pass data to shortcode & ajax render it

Answer (score 1):

Might somethink like this:

```
var gtitle = <?php echo do_shortcode() ?>;
```